# How to paste a byte array into a file c#?

Tags: c#, file, binary, copy

When my program starts, i get the byte array of a file (file a), then i send that byte array to paste it into another file (file b), like creating a copy of my first file.

The Question is, how do i open the "file b" and paste the binary info to create a copy of my "file a"?

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes

Comment: If all you are doing is simply copying the file, you should use `File.Copy(source, destination)`, which means you won't need to load the entire file into memory (problematic for large files) just to copy it.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to copy one file to another which is already answered in the past. If you really looking into constructing File object on clipboard to *paste* it as file later it would be completely different story - consider asking new question clearly specifying that.

Comment: the second file is not in my local machine, that's why i can´t use file.Copy

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Please refrain from closing questions of duplicates, when they aren't. The OP has specified in his question he is using a byte array, and wants to copy binary info across files. The dupe you selected clearly does not cover these scenarios.

Comment: @Matt it looked like copy files was the actual goal. Unfortunately I did not see checo's comment about file not being local. I'll try to be more careful in a future - downvote for lack of research was the only thing needed on this post.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a byte[] directly to a file path.

```
using System.IO;

byte[] byteArray;
string path = @"C:\fileB.txt"

File.WriteAllBytes(path, byteArray);
```